# Display MAUIIcon in normal Page

Tags: .net, maui, imagesource

I'm developing a .NET MAUI App. It has an MAUIIcon as AppIcon, so far so good.

But how is it possible to display this icon in an normal XAML contentPage?

I tried to use ImageSource.FromFile("AppIcon.png") but that doesent work. Even as trying to get it as embedded ressource.

Best regards

Comment: The simple answer is that you cannot directly use it for that. However, you can add a copy to the Images folder and then reference it by its filename as suggested in Liyun Zhang's answer below.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. I don't want to do a copy of the file. The file is compiled into the app, so why can't I use this file again?

Comment: Because it's not available as a resource that way. You would have to load it in a complicated way. Also, the app icon file is resized by the *Resizetizer* to match the platform-specific requirements for app icons and thus would be very small anyway. The updated approach seems feasible, though, where the same file is referenced in two different ways. Not sure if the *Resizetizer* will be able to handle that, but it sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the AppIcon image to the `\Resource\Images` folder and set its build action as **MauiImage**.

And then use it in the XAML:

```xml
<Image Source="AppIcon.png"/>
```

**Update:**

If you don't want to copy the file. You can try to use it by edit the following code in the Project's *.csproj* file:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <!-- App Icon -->
    <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

    <!-- Splash Screen -->
    <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

    <!-- Images -->
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
    <MauiImage Include="Resources\AppIcon\*" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg" BaseSize="168,208" />
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" BaseSize="168,168" />
    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

    <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
    <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

After this, you don't have to copy the app icon file. You can use it directly.

```xml
<Image HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="100" Source="appicon.png"/>
```

**Note:** You can see the default MauiIcon contains two file: appicon.svg and appiconfg.svg. So if you use the default `Source="appicon.png"`, you will only seem a purple image.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that sounds possible. But I don't want to have a copy of the appicon in another folder..

Comment: You can just make two same image files. One's buid action is MauiIcon and the other's build action is MauiImage. @user22801399

Comment: That doesn't work -> "One or more duplicate file names were detected.  All image output filenames must be unique: appicon"

Comment: Yes, you need to give it a different name, because the *Resizetizer* of MAUI cannot deal with duplicate file names even if they're in different locations. Just use a different name.

Comment: Hmm, how to give one file two different names?

Comment: You don't. You need a copy with a different build action and a different name.

Comment: You can change the copy file's name. In addition, you can check the update part in my answer. @user22801399

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT That update is a great idea. Does that work? Have you tried it?

Comment: I tried it on the windows. And it worked. I will try on android now. @Julian

Comment: It both worked on android and windows. @Julian

Comment: Hello, I tested the update of your tip, but here it doesn't work. Have you tested it on .NET7 or .NET8? Here I use .NET8 MAUI.

Comment: I tested on .Net 7.0. Can you show the details? @user22801399

Comment: I use .Net 8.0 RC2.
Here is what I use: 
<!-- App Icon -->
 <MauiIcon Include="Resources\_BARMER\AppIcon\appicon.png" />
 
 <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix)-->
 <MauiAsset Include="Resources\_BARMER\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />

Comment: Is the appicon.png your custom file? In addition, you can refer to the code in `<MauiImage>`. Or you can just create a new project and copy my code to test. @user22801399

Comment: Yes appicon.png is my appIcon, its png for now. After adding the line <MauiImage Include="Resources\_BARMER\AppIcon\*" /> I get the error again "One or more duplicate file names were detected.  All image output filenames must be unique: appicon (Resources\_BARMER\AppIcon\appicon.png)"

Comment: Can you show your project structure? There should be something wrong in `<MauiImage Include="Resources_BARMER\AppIcon*" />`? Did you has copied the appicon file? @user22801399

Comment: I recommend you to create a new project to test my code and then you will undersand why it worked. @user22801399

Comment: I tested today again, It doesn't work for me. VS is always saying duplicate file. I think I will test it in a sample project on monday, but in the end it need to be run in the project I showed you, its a transfer from Xamarin.Forms to MAUI .NET 8.0 with creating different apps in one project by choosing the build configuration.

Comment: If so, you can just copy the file and rename it to show it in the xaml. @user22801399

Comment: Yeah, I think I have to do it this way.